# Missing "Wine Windows Program Loader"

Tags: kubuntu, wine, plasma-5

Installed wine stable, winetricks, PoL, Q4wine. No "Wine Windows Program Loader" entry on Dolphin context menu, neither on KDE launcher menu. Can only open .exe via Q4wine or console.

Kubuntu 18.04(Almost fresh install)
linux 4.15.0-20-generic(x86_64)
Plasma 5.12.4

Answer (score 8):

Actually the launcher is misplaced in Ubuntu 18+, Ubuntu made a mistake, all the other distributions based on ubuntu including linux mint inherited the bug, nobody cared to fix

Run the below command in terminal

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/doc/wine-stable/examples/wine.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Now right click the windows app and click open with , you can now see open with "wine windows program loader" in the applications list.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the wine package by
`sudo apt purge wine`
And then install the stable version by
`sudo apt install wine-stable winehq-stable`
It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to purge my previous wine installation using `sudo apt purge wine64 wine32` and then headed to the wine official page to install it - https://winehq.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Kubuntu, but this is a known bug in Linux Mint. This might well be the case though since Mint is based on Ubuntu.

According to the bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/mintmenu/+bug/714848),

> "There are problems launching Wine-applications from MintMenu. Launching them from the desktop or panel works fine.
>
> The root cause seems to be the double backslash-escaping done in the launcher-file, so "C:\someprog" is encoded to "C:\\someprog", and "my file" is encoded to "my\ file". It seems mint menu while decoding is just decoding it once, causing failure."

This is not a wine issue according to the developers and needs to be fixed outside of wine. (https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27706#c2)

Comment: Hilarious, so they blame integration with file managers on the file manager teams? Sounds lame-O to me. Thanks for sharing though; good to know their "official stance" on why default installations have this feature broken on the majority of OSs.